# Can I use multiple case in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, case

Requirement:

Original Table: SCORE

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Math   | English  | Chemistry |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 69     | 82       | 95        |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Sort:
- [0-80] - > C
- [80-90] - > B
- [90-100] ->A

Output should be

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Math   | English  | Chemistry |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| C      | B        |    A      |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

I should test in Oracle, but now I firstly do it on MySQL. My code as follows:

```
CREATE table grade1(
Math varchar(10),
English varchar(10),
Chemistry varchar(10))

INSERT INTO grade1 (Math, English, Chemistry)
VALUES (

SELECT
CASE
when Math < 80 then 'C'
when Math > 80 and Math <90 then 'B'
when Math > 90 and Math <100 then 'A'
END
FROM SCORE,

SELECT
CASE
when English < 80 then 'C'
when English > 80 and English < 90 then 'B'
when English > 90 and English < 100 then 'A'
END
FROM SCORE,

SELECT
CASE
when Chemistry < 80 then 'C'
when Chemistry > 80 and Chemistry <90 then 'B'
when Chemistry > 90 and Chemistry <100 then 'A'
END  
FROM SCORE)
```

Please check if there's anything wrong? because I cannot run it.

Comment: What's the problem?  What do you mean by "cannot run it"?  What happens when you do?  Do you see errors?  Do you see the wrong output?  What do you see?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I mean the right output doesn't show up

Comment: So, what output _does_ show up, @user2946141? When asking questions always say (a) what you expected, and (b) what you actually got. It's a good idea to edit your question with this info too, so it is all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
INSERT INTO grade1 (Math, English, Chemistry)
    VALUES (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN Math >= 90 then 'A'
                WHEN Math >= 80 then 'B'
                WHEN Math < 80 then 'C'
            END Math,
            CASE
                WHEN English >= 90 then 'A'
                WHEN English >= 80 then 'B'
                WHEN English < 80 then 'C'
            END English,
            CASE
                WHEN Chemistry >= 90 then 'A'
                WHEN Chemistry >= 80 then 'B'
                WHEN Chemistry < 80 then 'C'
            END Chemistry
        FROM SCORE)
```

You don't have to use SELECT before each CASE. And I changed the order of the WHEN values from .